# Why are there many domain names resolving to IP like 8.8.8.8 and many other?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ip-address, domain-name, resolve

I have been wondering why are there many domain names assigning public address that already owned by other (apart from shared hosting/ip), for example hundreds or thousands domain names assigned (or resolving) public dns (e.g. 8.8.8.8) as their IP address: [8.8.8.8 IP address information](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/8.8.8.8/information/) and many other.

- Is this even allowed and what is the purpose of it?
- Are there any pros and cons about it?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is a google dns server ip

Comment: *Is this even allowed?* Yes, of course. *what is the purpose of it?* Dunno

Comment: #masegaloeh thanks.
@RichieFrame I know that of course, I have stated that e.g. from public dns. 

The problem is I have never heard and known about this, and it's not even stated as something probably a reverse dns/ip hijacking/spoofing attack. That's why I asked, probably if there's someone who knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how adding an `A` record like this serves any meaningful purpose.
It's hard to come up with pros for a practice that appears completely misguided.

As for cons, for the owner of the domain name it's pretty much just that the name in question resolves to an address that will not provide much in terms of services (`8.8.8.8` will almost assuredly not do whatever they had in mind). From Google's perspective there's the irrelevant types of traffic that this will attract to their servers.

As for it being allowed, on a technical level there is absolutely nothing stopping it. It does appear very strange, though, and I'm sure it would be considered bad etiquette by some.